# DRF - Foreign key in a non-model serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a non-model serializer which looks like this:

```
class NonModelSerializer(Serializer):
    secret_number = IntegerField()
    user = ???

    def save(**kwargs):
        ... do something with the secret number and user ...
```

What shall be written instead of `???` so that my serializer accepts ID of a user and in `save()` method, I see the user of the given ID in the `user` field? Something like `ModelChoiceField` from plain Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`,:

```
class NonModelSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    secret_number = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('user', 'secret_number')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(self.validated_data)
    pass

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass
```

I suggest you override `create` and `update` instead of `save`, but you can access the selected user in `save` by `self.validated_data` too.